# Python-Neo4j Security error while connecting to database Failed to establish secure connection to '[SSL:UNKNOWN_PROTCOL(_ssl.c:600)

Tags: python, django, neo4j, graph-databases

Im trying to connect the Django to Neo4j using neo4j-driver but I'm getting Security  error.

**Error is** :- `neo4j.exceptions.SecurityError: Failed to establish secure connection to '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:600)'`

**Python Version 3.4.3 IN MACOSX**

**My Dependencies**

```
django1.9 
neo4j-driver==1.4.0
```

**CODE**
Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase,basic_auth
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse,Http404
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django import template



uri = "bolt://localhost:7474"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "password"))


def friends(request):
    name = "Cameron Crowe"
    with driver.session() as session:
        with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
            for record in tx.run("MATCH (a:Person)-[:PRODUCED]->(f) "
                                 "WHERE a.name = {name} "
                                 "RETURN f.title", name=name):
                print(record["f.title"])

    return render(request, "friends.html")
```

**Error**

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/neo4/neo4/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from graphdb.views import friends
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/neo4/graphdb/views.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://127.0.0.1:7474", auth= basic_auth("neo4j", "aditya369")).session()
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 124, in driver
    return driver_class(uri, **config)
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neo4j/v1/direct.py", line 65, in __init__
    pool.release(pool.acquire())
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neo4j/v1/direct.py", line 39, in acquire
    connection = self.acquire_direct(address)  # should always be a resolved address
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 398, in acquire_direct
    connection = self.connector(address)
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neo4j/v1/direct.py", line 64, in <lambda>
    pool = DirectConnectionPool(lambda a: connect(a, security_plan.ssl_context, **config), self.address)
  File "/Users/sskadit/Desktop/graphdb/src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 501, in connect
    raise error
neo4j.exceptions.SecurityError: Failed to establish secure connection to '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:600)'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks Rishabh for writing a solution to the question.

I later realized that port number 7474 is used for http protocol for ssl use.

I have changed the URL  form `uri = "bolt://localhost:7474"` to `uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"`

Worked like charm !!

Answer (score 1):

Browser was showing port 9987 and i was getting exception while using this port. It worked when i changed the port in python to 7687

Answer (score 0):

This was reported in a [Github issue here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9233). Does the following work for you?

1. Uninstall neo4j driver using `pip uninstall neo4j-driver`
2. Run the command `echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && apt update && apt install -y -t jessie-backports openssl` in the terminal
3. Reinstall neo4j-driver `pip install neo4j-driver`

Comment: Hi @Rishabh Srivastava Thanks for the reply but I'm using a macosx so this echo command will not work cause it has apt update and apt install